# Cannot use keyboard while in Kiosk mode

Tags: qt, ubuntu, keyboard, kiosk

I need to launch an app I've made just after login, before anything else is loaded. I found how to do it by browsing, and my app just launch as i want, but when i need to input something using keyboard, nothing happens, what can I do?

It is a QT App

This is the main script who launchs the desired app (Ensayo):

#!/bin/bash
xscreensaver -nosplash & 
/home/me/Ensayo-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH_*System*_Release/Ensayo

Comment: sorry about that, Im running Ubuntu 12.04. when I'm talking about kiosk mode is the proper ubuntu kiosk mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the window manager is not started. The [instructables article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS) you refer to specifically starts Firefox without a window manager.

Install the matchbox window manager, and modify your script as follows:

```
matchbox-window-manager &
while true; do
  /home/me/Ensayo-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH_System_Release/Ensayo
done
```

Note that Firefox is designed, apparently, to run without a window manager. If you try other applications, such as gnumeric, openoffice, konsole -- I bet they won't behave correctly either. Not without a window manager.

The trivial test for a window manager is: try showing a message box in your application. If the message box doesn't appear, or appears without any window frame/title bar, then it's surely due to lack of window manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the main script which launch the app (Ensayo):                                    
#!/bin/bash
xscreensaver -nosplash & 
/home/me/Ensayo-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/Ensayo

Comment: How do you launch that script? Where from? I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, but please try to check if mouse input to your application is working. If it isn't, then probably the window manager is not running. Alternatively, is there a kiosk setting that locks out the keyboard?

Comment: I created a kiosk.desktop file who call that script, (following this tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS). Really i dont know a lot about kiosk mode, only thing i can tell you is that mouse is perfectly working. Again man THANK YOU

Comment: And when i press the interface buttons also works in the way they are supposed to do, only thing left is the keyboard

Comment: The instructable you've provided is the wrong way of doing it: they start the application without the window manager, and that's why keyboard doesn't work.

Comment: but i've tried to run other programs in that way, such as Firefox, and they work preety well

Comment: Hey man!!! It really did the trick!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU for your help!!! but i must ask you one last thing, is there any way to vote you possitive for your help, Im new in stackoverflow!

Comment: Whenever you get enough reputation, feel free to cast the vote. I'm glad I could help.